# FB.ui apprequests method

Tags: facebook, apprequests

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'come on man checkout my application.'});
```

When I invoke this method I am getting prompt with friend list and send request button. In notification area "ABC" sent you request in "XYZ" is visible but Message is not visible. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

When you prompt a user with an app request, the message will be visible only when you fetch it from the graph api with me/apprequests. If the invited user clicks on a notification one will be forwarded to your apps canvas page and you will get the request ids as a GET parameter, so you will know exactly what you have to display to.

Everything is clearly explained [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#user_to_user).

Following [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/requests/) will give you useful information about best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't closed your `message` with a `'` on line 2.

Comment: This was a sample message and I guess I forgot to close my message here. I checked thing thing in my app and it is closed. Still it isn't working.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding the requestcallback to the end of the arguments and at the end of the function.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'come on man checkout my application.',
          }, requestCallback);}
function requestCallback(response) {//redirect or whatever...}
```